# Python Pandas not reading DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in a csv file into a pandas dataframe and then set the column to the specified columns in columns=[ ... ]

Would anyone now why its not reading in all of my data? p

```
fp = '/Users/USERNAME/Development/file.csv'
file1 = open(fp, 'rb').read()
reader = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(fp, index_col=False, sep=',')

df = pd.DataFrame(reader, columns=['VIN', 'Reg City','First Name','Last Name','MGVW','Nat Flt Ind','MGVW',
                                    'Reg Name','Phone', 'Unnamed: 8','ZIP','VC','VType', 
                                    'Reg Voc', 'Make','Veh Model', 'E Mfr','Engine Model', 
                                    'CY2010', 'CY2011', 'CY2012', 'CY2013', 'CY2014', 'CY2015', 
                                    'Std Cnt',])

#reader.head(1)
df.head(1)
```

> VIN   Reg City    First Name  Last Name   MGVW    Nat Flt Ind MGVW    Reg
>   Name  Phone   Unnamed: 8  ... Veh Model   E Mfr   Engine
>   Model CY2010  CY2011  CY2012  CY2013  CY2014  CY2015  Std Cnt 0   NaN KANSAS
>     NaN NaN NaN N   NaN ACE PIPE CLNG INC   NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN 0   1

Comment: You'll need to post your raw input data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version to load only certain colunns.
set `usecols`in `pd.read_csv()`.

```
import pandas as pd

fp = '/Users/USERNAME/Development/file.csv'

usecols = ['VIN', 'Reg City','First Name','Last Name','MGVW','Nat Flt Ind','MGVW',
                                'Reg Name','Phone', 'Unnamed: 8','ZIP','VC','VType', 
                                'Reg Voc', 'Make','Veh Model', 'E Mfr','Engine Model', 
                                'CY2010', 'CY2011', 'CY2012', 'CY2013', 'CY2014', 'CY2015', 
                                'Std Cnt']

df = pd.read_csv(fp, usecols=usecols, sep=',')

print df.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `df = pd.read_csv('/Users/USERNAME/Development/file.csv')`
to load your CSV file. If I am not mistaken, `from_csv` as been replaced by `read_csv`.

Comment: But i only want to see certain columns. further down I have more code written, and I want to sort by zipcodes blue = df[df.ZIP.isin(zipBlue)] and then write that output into a file, which works well. But it writes every column into the file and I only need a few of them.

Comment: OK but you can load your all your csv first into dataframe and then select the columns you need by doing `df = df[['col1', 'col2']]`

Comment: Thanks Plug4. Could you give me an example of when I would use df = pd.DataFrame(reader, columns=[...]  could I still use it when reading in a csv file? Or  was I simply heading in the wrong direction?

Comment: Avoid the `reader` or `from_csv` option. Its depleted I believe. There is a lot more built-in options with `read_csv` http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html